# PHP - Why call to session_start() generates unusual empty session files?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I am working on PHP Session management for my website. I found that even if I do not put any value to `$_SESSION`, the `session_start()` still generates unusual empty session files in the corresponding session files directory. How can I stop this to not generate useless session files and only generate session files when `$_SESSION` is populated with some values?

Thanks!!!

Comment: session_start does what its called..it creates the file/row to associate the id. what are you trying to achieve what session garbage collection doesn't do?

Comment: Those files are not unusual. Why does it matter if they are empty?

Answer (score 1):

They're not useless. Let's say John visits the site and gets session ID **abc**. Perhaps the site doesn't generate session data until much later on, but John still has the same session ID.

Now let's say that Mary visits the site a few minutes after John does, and PHP wants to give her the session ID of **abc**, too.

If the empty session file exists, then PHP knows that ID is in use, so it gives Mary a different session ID instead.

If it didn't have that file, then Mary might share the same session ID as John and end up seeing his data later, when the server populates John's data.

Granted the chance of a session ID collision is rare but it's better to be safe than sorry.

EDIT: If you're not populating a lot of sessions, you could always try to reduce the pages that call session_start() so it's only called when it's actually used.

Comment: So i cannot stop this thing?

Comment: Not if you use the default session handler (at least not to my knowledge). That said, PHP does allow you to implement custom session handling, so if you are concerned about empty files, you could either implement your own (which is a very bad idea) or use a common community-tested alternative like database records instead of files.